# php call_user_func variable error

Tags: php

I'm just feeling my way around with some tests to get an idea of how to tackle a coding issue. Now, I'm getting behavior I don't understand.

```
function product($a, $b) {
echo "Yo ".$a;
echo "Yo ".$b;
}

call_user_func('product', 'dd', 'lizzy');
```

The above works, however,

```
$variablename = "'product','dd','lizzy'";
call_user_func($variablename);
```

throws an error:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ''product','dd','lizzy'' not found or invalid function name

Obviously $variablename contains the same values.

Anyone any hint for me to put me back on track?

Comment: What is the content of $variablename? `var_dump($variablename)`

Comment: The exact same.

Comment: string(22) "'product','dd','lizzy'"

Comment: There is the error. `call_user_func($func_name, $argument1, $argument2)` needs the function name as a single string variable. Each argument needs to be an extra argument. You can use use `call_user_func_array` similar. One argument for the name, one argument as array for all arguments to the user function.

Comment: i cant imagine why you would ever want to do this.

Comment: @Dagon you can write functions like `function do_something_on($some_var, callable $callback){foreach(...)}`. Hook design pattern works similar.

Comment: thats not what he is doing here

Comment: @Dragon The questions fits (tries to) the SO format "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the signature of `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array`.

```
function product($a, $b) {
  echo "Yo ".$a;
  echo "Yo ".$b;
  echo "<br>\n";
}

// there are 3 single arguments
call_user_func('product', 'dd', 'lizzy');

// the same with variables
$fn_name = 'product';
$arg1    = 'dd';
$arg2    = 'lizzy';

call_user_func($fn_name, $arg1, $arg2);

// or give ARGUMENS ONLY as array, but function name as string scalar
$args    = array($arg1, $arg2);
call_user_func_array($fn_name, $args);

// if you for some reason need to handle a single array for the name and arguments in one,
// you need to write your own function:
function call_user_func_array2($call_info)
{
  $fn_name = array_shift($call_info);  //extract first item
  call_user_func_array($fn_name, $call_info);
}

$call_info = array($fn_name, $arg1, $arg2);
call_user_func_array2($call_info);
```

In addition we can extend the code above to process on a given string `"'product','dd','lizzy'"`. (e.g. in situations when it is stored in this form in some database)

You first need to extract the comma separated values in this string. You can achieve this by `str_getcsv` or more flexible by a regular expression. Let's say it is separated by comma with optional whitespaces and enclosed in single *or* double qoutes. The regex could look like: `(?:^|,)\s*(['"])(.+?)\1\s*?(?=,|$)`. The **2**nd subpatter `(.+?)` will capture everything inside the single/double quotes.

Combined with `call_user_func_array2` it looks like that:

```
function call_user_func_string($call_info)
{
  if(!preg_match_all('~(?:^|,)\s*([\'"])(.+?)\1\s*?(?=,|$)~u', $call_info, $matches))
    throw new Exception("call_user_func_string expects parameter 1 to be a string like `'functionname','arg1','arg2' [,...]` "
                      . 'or `"functionname","arg1","arg2" [,...]`.');

  call_user_func_array(array_shift($matches[2]), $matches[2]);
}


// some differently formatted examples

$my_string = "'product','dd','lizzy'";
call_user_func_string($my_string);

$my_string = '  "product"  ,  "dd"  ,  "lizzy"  ';
call_user_func_string($my_string);

$my_string = <<<'_END_'
    'product'   ,   "dd",'lizzy'    ,"lucy's cat"   
_END_;

call_user_func_string($my_string);
```

Comment: so like every one else has said, no you can't do that.

Comment: No, I say: "You *can* do that. Learn the correct syntax and signature of functions".

Comment: you can, if you do it a completely different way, ok that's clear.

Comment: Thanks! To put it in layman's terms; while you can put the function name in a variable, it still expects the arguments separate. That makes sense in one way and is completely counter intuitive in another way... but that's life. ;-)

I understand newbs asking questions can be annoying, but we all have to learn, and Googling didn't solve this for me, as I was thinking along the wrong lines. You lot gave me that push on the right track I was after. Every answer seems correct and each would have helped me. But the long one got my vote since it will help other newbs best, I think.

Comment: It might be counter intuitive to some absolute beginners, however, you will often want want to map an array to the argument list of a specific function. It's in most situations easier to keep it separate. Also the invocation `some_func($arg1, $arg2)` distinguishes between the function identifier and the argument list. So it's not too counter intuitive once you got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding what you didn't precisely show, your 2nd try looks like this:

```
$variablename = "'product', 'dd', 'lizzy'";
call_user_func($variablename);
```

When executing the 2nd line, `$variablename` is the *only* argument, while `call_user_func()` expects three.

And so the error you get is pretty normal!
Definetly you can't expect *one* argument to be "dispatched" into several ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [PHP Docs on call_user_func](http://php.net/call_user_func), you should see that it requires at least one parameter -- and that first parameter has to be of type [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

> Obviously $variablename contains the same values.

Not sure how this is obvious. Nothing in your code defines this value. It should specify some function or object-and-method (see the callable link above).

Comment: Seeing your subsequent post, it looks like $variablename is a string and that its contents are NOT a function name.

Answer (score 1):

From the error telling;

the first argument need to be valid callback/function name.

when you set `$variablename` like you mention above, sure it will be trown a error.

`"'product', 'dd', 'lizzy'` it not a valid callback name in your case.